# Android SDK manager SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: android, sdk

When I try using Android SDK manager to download the ARM EABI for Android 4.1 it refuses to to install it. I get the following message: "SSL peer shut down incorrectly". This is on a Windows XP OS. Any idea what is happening here and what I can do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 48):

The problem is caused by some kind of incompatibility with HTTPS.

For solve this, in the Android SDK settings, in "SDK Update Sites" tab, at bottom, check the option "**Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...**".

Then try again to download the package.

Comment: but i can't find Options in the tools menu , I am using Android Studio 2.3.2

Comment: In recent versions of Android Studio, the Android SDK settings is located inside Android Studio settings. In Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK there are a tab called "SDK Update Sites", at the bottom of this section is the option "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."

Comment: I have the same issue. I've checked "Force https: /..." restarted android studio, it is having the same problem.

Comment: Problem to this answer is, can't activate that "SDK Update site" tab. when there is no valid Android SDK folder on computer, exactly when installing the AndroidStudio first time.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are trying to access a https link using http protocol. 
By default android allows only http requests.
To change go to

**File-->Settings-->System Settings --> Android SDK **

Click on SDK Update Sites tab. At the bottom check **Force https// sources to be fetched using http//**

Happy Coding

Answer (score 5):

Open Android SDK Manager
Go to SDK Update sites
Check Force https// sources to be fetched using http

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No matter how stupid it sounds, on Mac restarting the computer solves the problem. I spent several hours trying to fix the problem, restarted the computer for some reason and it worked.

I got the same problem after a couple months, restarting the computer solved the problem again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, i must DISABLE VPN, otherwise it can't download gradle zip in the gradle-wrapper.properties file :

File: gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet connection and restart Android Studio. I have faced this error due to unavailability of internet.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download the particular version you wish to download from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

2.Modify the `distributionUrl` in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to version you have downloaded. For example, `gradle-4.6-all.zip`

3.Paste the file to the location `~/AndroidStudioProjects/YourProjectFolder/gradle/wrapper/`

Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

__ clean and rebuild ... not working
__ force https.. not working

I fixed it by this way.

1-  open the gradle-wrapper.properties file, Modify the distributionUrl

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

2- exchange https by http and sync after running and downloading little part stop it and then turn it back to https and sync .. voila it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the last version which is Giraffe, find the
**File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Android SDK**
You can see SDK updates menu in the frame. Click, and there is Force https// sources to be fetched using http// option, click the checkbox to make checked.

Now, you're ready to work)