# Can not use flutter run command to run my flutter app

Tags: flutter

When I use `flutter run` command on my flutter project , it stuck for a long time in Running gradle taks then give me the following error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)

        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)

        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)

        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)

        at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:85)

        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)

        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3517)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:77)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:596)

        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)

        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)

        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)

        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)

        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)

        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)

        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)

        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)

        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3444)

        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3437)

        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)

        ... 7 more
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            386.4s (!)
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I try to wipe AVD data from android studio AVD manager, but it also gives the same error
When i run flutter doctor, there is no any issues

Can anyone help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: Which JRE you are using?

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same problem and the solution is to have a internet bandwidth of more than 1 MiB/s (make sure android studio is connected) and it downloads about 1 GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25117#issuecomment-447249067) on GitHub.

This error is due to network issue and not coming from Flutter, usually related to proxy config, self-signed certificates or some network problems (being blocked in China for example). You can try this solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23727#issuecomment-435019094).

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629999/errorssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-android-studio-3-0-1) if it helps you resolve the problems.