# How to enable the default indexing of files before building gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Every time during assembly I see it
"Indexing paused due to batch updated"

[image]

> I want it to be as before, first indexing the files, and then the
>   build.

And I did not have to wait until the end of the assembly or manually press the start button for indexing.

Please tell me how it can be customized and is it possible?

I know about [Indexing freeze with message: Indexing paused due to batch updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513097/indexing-freeze-with-message-indexing-paused-due-to-batch-updated) 
but I have no problems with hangs, **my problem is that the indexing is suspended while the project is building.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indexing freeze with message: Indexing paused due to batch updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513097/indexing-freeze-with-message-indexing-paused-due-to-batch-updated)

Comment: sorry, this question does not answer my question

Comment: it's probably supposed to be like that ...like it, whether or not. just click the small minimize icon top-right and you won't see it anymore. pretend it wouldn't be there. problem "fixed". this is probably more of a psychological problem, than it would be a technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Cache and Restart worked for me.

Just Goto File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Answer (score -1):

deleting `.iml` file and `.idea` folder will solve your problem

Comment: thanks for the answer but it did not solve my problem