# Android Studio 3.3 Stuck at Project Setup:reading from cache

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have create module library with NDK. After updating Android Studio 3.3, open project on studio stuck on build project

> Project Setup:reading from cache...

Every time needs to **"Invalidate and Restart"** android studio then after studio working.

I have try to delete **`.gradle`** folder but still facing this issue.

How can I solved this misbehavior of studio 3.3?

Comment: try clean project , If not helps try deleting  .idea/caches , build , .gradle and rebuild again

Comment: I have the same issue with NDK. Can't compile. arggg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post this as an answer.

- **After** you **Invalidate and Restart** have you tried **Build->Clean Project** and rebuilding then syncing again?
- Have you tried restarting your computer to turn of any processes that may keep caches from clearing?
- Have you tried upgrading your gradle version as well (inside your gradle-wrapper.properties)?
- Have you checked if your gradle path is correct at **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle**?
- Have you tried locating your gradlew and doing a `gradlew cleanBuildCache`?
- Have you tried removing the `C:\Users\{Your Username}\.gradle\caches` folder?
- Have you tried disabling cache building altogether (will slow down your build and is not recommended)? To do this you have to go to your gradle.properties file and set `android.enableBuildCache=false`

Comment: Already used latest gradle version and also try "gradlew cleanBuildCache" but still not issue resolved. @sansa

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try disabling build cache altogether and see if it works. Also have you even restarted your PC? @JigarShekh

Comment: Try this "android.enableBuildCache=false" and close android studio. After reopen studio on getting warning:: "WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableBuildCache=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.
Affected Modules: app, commonlib" @sansa

Comment: Yes, this is not recommended, just wanted to see if it worked. Anyway, after you **invalidate and restart** did you do a **Build -> Clean Project** Then rebuilt it and synced it? However, I would just say restart your computer so any processes turn off and cache can clear without a problem when you start android studio again.

Comment: What finally worked for me was file->invalidate caches/restart.  See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513097/indexing-freeze-with-message-indexing-paused-due-to-batch-updated

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle** caches are at

- On **macOS**/**Linux**: `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`
- On **Windows**: `%USER_HOME%\.gradle/caches/`

Try to delete those directories.

More about build caches is here: [Android Studio Build Cache](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache)

Also, **Disable configuration on demand** in your `gradle.properties` file as shown below:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

See: [Known issues with the Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#known_issues_with_the_android_gradle_plugin)

Comment: I have deleted "%USER_HOME%\.gradle" directory and reopen android studio but unfortunately not resolved my issue. @shizhen

Comment: Probably it is a daemon issue, try to stop your daemon using `./gradlew --stop`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below approach:

Go to "

> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run"

and just disable it.

With this Android Studio builds from scratch each time but it's better than not building it right.

Comment: Already disable it. But still facing this issue. @Chetan Joshi

Answer (score 0):

open your project's gradle.perperties file and add settings:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

restart your projects