# The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip' does not appear to contain a Gradle distribution

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have two projects. One project is working without any issues. It was downloaded from gitlab. The other project was downloaded from github. github project has this issue. I want to use default gradle distribution. I want to know what wrong I did. 
Using local gradle distribution builds the project. But i get other issue - Precondition class not found. This issue is not my question here. Also I dont know if the gradle (local distribution or default) is causing the issue. Those things aside. I just want to know why I am getting - The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip' does not appear to contain a Gradle distribution.

My team mates are not having any problem. They are running the project without any issues. The project which is building correctly used gradle 4.10.1. This project uses 4.6.

The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip' does not appear to contain a Gradle distribution.

Comment: see [how to clean up the gradle caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586472/8034839)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by upgrading the Gradle Version (not the Android Gradle Plugin Version). Go to Project Structure -> Project [image: example here]

After this, Gradle re-downloaded all dependencies and the build was successful.

Comment: For anyone that still has issues, or wants to keep the same version, try deleting the Gradle-wrapper at `$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/<your_wrapper_version>`. After that, try syncing the project. NOTE: while deleting the Gradle-wrapper, you will need to close AS.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i solved it by adding multidex support

Comment: thanks @miguelarc, your suggestion working on my case.. i think that's other solution..

Comment: @VijaiGunasekar Since this answer is working for most people facing this particular error, you may want to consider it as one possible correct (even if it didn't apply for your specific case). Don't know if SO allows for multiple correct answers.

Comment: I copied the gradle number from working project and paste at the above specified location in the project which has problem , now resolve the issues.

Comment: Does anybody know why this happens though? It's a shame that a project that worked before without any local changes would suddenly stopped being able to build itself a couple of months later.

Comment: @miguelarc thanks so much! That worked great. I was in the same boat as Andrew, where a working project suddenly wouldn't build...

Comment: @AndrewLim my guess is certain Gradle references won't get updated when Gradle is updated. Once a new version is installed, Gradle is still looking for old references, hence the errors. It has happened to me in different versions in the past.

Answer (score 16):

I managed to fix this by updating the gradle version number in Project Structure in Android Studio 3.4.1

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i solved it by adding multidex support

Answer (score 8):

The only think that works for me was:

1. Click on the error link to download the gradle zip.
2. Then go to `C:\Users\YourUsername\.gradle\native` and drop the
   content of the zip.
3. Open AndroidStudio, go to `File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle`
4. Change "Use Gradle from:" to "Specified location" and paste the
   direction `C:\Users\YourUsername\.gradle\native\NameOfTheZipContent`
5. Apply, Ok
6. Sometimes needs to open/close AndroidStudio

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i solved it by adding multidex support

Comment: Did not work for me. Only starting AS as administrator is working for me. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @Shweta never, ever, run Android Studio as administrator. If this "fixes" it is a permission issue, you should fix the permission issue instead

Answer (score 6):

Well, I tried all of the above solutions except for miguelarc's second solution, then I closed it and 'run android studio as administrator'(by right clicking on the icon), and it auto downloaded the gradle files just fine.
No messing around with the files or change in settings were required for me.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i solved it by adding multidex support

Comment: That's what worked for me too. Windows sometimes is a pain in the as*.

Comment: never, ever, run Android Studio as administrator. If this "fixes" it is a permission issue, you should fix the permission issue instead

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved the same problem.
Try to exit Android Studio. Then, open again with "Run as administrator"

Comment: never, ever, run Android Studio as administrator. If this "fixes" it is a permission issue, you should fix the permission issue instead

Comment: You're right. That's not the correct way to fix it.