# Error while downloading google APIs Intel x86 atom system image

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, android-virtual-device

I just started to work with Android Studio and I stuck with one problem . 
When I try to download a system image and create an AVD I get this error

> " Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 9) failed

and no matter what API level and what release I try to download, I get this error anyway ...
 any solutions ??

[This is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbe09.jpg)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571201/android-sdk-manager-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly

Comment: Didnt work .....

Comment: Is this C:\AndroidSDK an sdk downloaded from the internet?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Yes I downloaded the sdk folders separately and I got no problems but this one ... !!

Comment: When and where did you get the sdk? (I really need to know both.)

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException There was an Iranian website for android developers which I don't really remember the address. I visited that maybe about a week ago and found the SDK folders then I downloaded them and made the folder and gave the path to android studio !! why is that so necessary ?

Comment: Because the **official** SDK tools are no longer available for download - please use the SDK provided in Android Studio! You have no clue whether it is safe to use @aliirezap and if you still insist on using it please add the structure of the sdk in your post.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Thank You !! And please tell me how do i do that ? Remove the current folder and download the official sdk from android studio's sdk manager ??? Is it important which API level and release do I download ?

Comment: No. **Please use the SDK bundled with Android Studio**.

Answer (score 27):

*1-* Do not close the installer

*2-* Click on "show details"

*3-* Inside the installer it gives for you this link: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-30_r09.zip

*4-* Access it and make the download manually

*5-* Go to
---Your main root (C: for example) -> **Users** -> **Your main user** -> **Enable "show oculted files"** -> **AppData** -> **Local** -> **Android** -> **Sdk**

*6-* Search for google_apis (at the search bar)

*7-* Open the x86-30_r09.zip and copy the files inside x86 folder

*8-* At google_apis enter at x86 folder and paste the files

*9-* Click "Retry" on the installer's error message.

If it stop again with the other download, you can do the same steps but using the another link for x86-2 file

Comment: This did the job! Thank you very much :))
Just, in my case, I didn't have the x86 folder inside the google_apis folder, but, when I extracted the  x86-30_r09.zip, it extracted itself into a folder named x86, so everything turned out great! :D

Comment: If you close installer (press Finish button) and make all steps from 3 to 8, at next app run you will get new installer, but nothing will be installed cause you already manually add all necessary files. I guess Internet access should be.

Comment: When I followed your suggestion and click retry button. This act is generating another alias folder of '`x86_64` and tried to download from google again same as earlier and issue is still persist. Not solved the issue. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 9):

###### Defining the problem

I faced the same problem while installing Android SDK on Windows OS:

> Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 9) failed

I went through the blogs to fix the problem. The problem is that the following subfolder is not created: `%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86`

*NOTE:* The name of the `android-30` folder changes according to the API level.

This issue is caused by Android Studio running without administrative privileges during installation. So don't try to install Android SDK after installing Android Studio; close Android Studio and run it again with administrative privileges. Follow the steps below to fix the problem:

###### Step-1

Run Android Studio with admin privileges:

[image]

###### Step-2

To install Android SDK, open Android Studio and follow these steps:

1. File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
2. Select the desired SDK and wait for the installation to complete.

[image]

Comment: This is one of the correct answers, just run the Android Studio with administrative privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK manager and then search **Optimize Disk Space** on top right.
Use **Optimize Disk Space** to clean the error stored part of **INTEL ATOM SYSTEM IMAGE**. Now, Update or download it again.

Comment: This one did it for me

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 20.04**
Remove `.downloadIntermediates/` folder from your SDK location `/.../Android/Sdk/`

Answer (score 0):

### Use the Android SDK bundled with Android Studio.

In `Preferences > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`

Edit the Android SDK path:

For Windows:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

For MacOS X:

`/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: I Un-installed and Re-installed android studio . I deleted all the folders to un-install it completely. There is no Android folder in AppData>Local and also all the check-boxes in android studio sdk manager is disabled. When I create Android folder and also sdk folder inside that manually in AppData>Local and give the path to android studio sdk manager I get the error " SDK tools directory is missing"

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Android SDK bundled with Xamarin Visual Studio.**

- Close the Andriod SDK
- Rebuild the Solution
- Clean the Solution
- Once again open the Andriod SDK in Visual Studio and then download