# Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 16)" failed

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, intel, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to download a system image and create an AVD but I'm getting the following error: "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 16)" failed"

any solutions to this problem?
[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows follow the steps:

1-> Download manually https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-26_r16.zip

2-> Browse to c:\users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-XX\google_apis
**([android-XX] <-check your version /example: [android-26] in your case)**

3-> Open x86_64-26_r16.zip (downloaded with step 1) and extract into "Step 2".

4-> At the end of the extraction make sure you have a folder created called x86_64 inside the "Step 2". If yes then Restart Android Studio (when starting will automatically recognize).

If not solved check the credit link.

[Credits: Guilherme Simionato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583286)