# The following SDK component was not installed: Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, sdk

[image]

I'm facing this issue. I'm trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583286/3158312